# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^8 -1}{x^{10} + 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^8 -1}{x^{10}  + 1} dx$$

---

Attempt:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^8-1}{x^{10}+1}$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^8 -1}{x^{10}  + 1} dx$$

Substituting $t = \frac{1}{x}$,

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\frac{1}{x^8} -1}{\frac{1}{x^{10}}  + 1} x^2dx$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4} - x^{12}}{x^{10}  + 1} dx$$

Adding the two versions of $I$,

$$2I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^8 - x^{12} -1 + x^4}{x^{10}  + 1} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^8-1)(1 - x^{4}) }{x^{10}  + 1} dx$$

---

However, that does not help much.

Putting it in WolframAlpha gives $I = 0$

I am pretty sure there is an elegant solution which I am not able to find it.

Comment: The substitution has been done incorrectly, you put $x^2dx$ instead of $dx/x^2$ in there. Once you do that it is easy to see that the integral vanishes.

Comment: I think you made  a mistake when when you changed the variable $t=\frac 1 x$. The $x^2$ factor should be in the denominator, and it should  lead  to $-I$  on the right-hand side.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg You guys are right. I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DinosaurEgg and @StefanLafon note, in fact $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-x^8}{x^{10}+1}dx=-I$ after the substitution, so $I$ is $0$ if it converges. Indeed, the integrand is $O(1)$ for small $x$ and $O(1/x^2)$ for large $x$.

Answer (score 4):

with $x = e^u$ and $dx = e^u du,$ I got
$$ \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{e^{4u} - e^{-4u}}{e^{5u} + e^{-5u}} du =  \int_{- \infty}^\infty \; \frac{ \sinh 4u \; }{ \cosh 5u \;} du$$
which is an odd integrand over symmetric endpoints